# Checkbox always returns false even though I only have one Tkinter window?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My code kind of sucks but here it is. This is the first program I'm writing using the TK interface and it's not going that well. I would like to save entered email and recipient so that they are available in the future in the drop down menu. Yet the checkbox always returns false so I can't save the emails into text files.

```
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk()
def donothing():
    print('Wagwan')

def printname():
    print("Well there's more code to write")
    print (state)
    if state == True:
        recipientread= open("recipient.txt","a+")
        recipientread.close() 
        senderread= open("sender.txt","a+")
        senderline = senderread.read().splitlines()
        for i in senderline:
            print(i)
        senderread.close()
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)


subMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Saved Recipient", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="Wagwan@gmail.com",command=donothing)
subMenu.add_command(label="MichealPeterWaldron@gmail.com",command=donothing)

subMenu.add_command(label="SuckyourMum@gmail.com",command=donothing)

editMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Saved Sender", menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="Wasteman@gmail.com", command=donothing)
editMenu.add_command(label="Battyboi@gmail.com",command=donothing)

label_1 = Label(root,text="Sender Email Adress:")
label_2 = Label(root,text="Recepient Email Adress:")
entry_1 = Entry(root)
entry_2 = Entry(root)
label_3 = Label(root,text="Email Info:")
button_1 = Button(root, text="Next", command=printname)

button_1.bind("<Button-1>")

label_1.grid(row=2,sticky=E)
label_2.grid(row=3,sticky=E)
label_3.grid(row=0,sticky=E)
button_1.grid(row=5,column=1)

entry_1.grid(row=2,column=1)
entry_2.grid(row=3,column=1)
state = BooleanVar()
c = Checkbutton(root,text="Remember these Emails",variable=state,command=printname)
c.grid(row=5,column=0, columnspan=1)
state = state.get()
print (state)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have to call `get` at the time you want the current value.

Comment: Thanks that seemed to be the problem.